# Generic derivation of type class instance for ADT

Tags: scala, typeclass, shapeless

Suppose I've got an ADT and type class `Foo` like this:

```
sealed trait A
case class A1() extends A
case class A2() extends A
case class A3() extends A

trait Foo[X] { def foo(x: X): String; }
object Foo {
  implicit val a1foo = new Foo[A1] { def foo(a1: A1) = "A1" }
  implicit val a2foo = new Foo[A2] { def foo(a2: A2) = "A2" }
  implicit val a3foo = new Foo[A3] { def foo(a3: A3) = "A3" }
}
```

Now I can write `Foo[A]` like that:

```
implicit val afoo = new Foo[A] {
  def foo(a: A) = a match {
    case a1 : A1 => a1foo.foo(a1)
    case a2 : A2 => a2foo.foo(a2)
    case a3 : A3 => a3foo.foo(a3)
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this code is too *boilerplaty*. Is it possible to get rid of all that boilerplate and *derive* `Foo[A]` automatically (perhaps with `shapeless`) ?

Comment: Is `implicit def fromA[A](a: A): Foo[A] = new Foo[A] { def foo(a: A) = a.getClass.getSimpleName }` enough? It will compile `Foo.fromA(A1).foo(A1)` and not `Foo.fromA(A1).foo(A2)`.

Comment: Is `getClass.getSimpleName` a runtime-reflection call ?

Comment: Yes, but I added it for illustration. You know inside `foo` A type.

Comment: @ipoteka I did not get it, sorry.  Could you write more detailed answer ?

Comment: Shapeless is indeed something you can use to solve the problem. It will require writing more code than what you have listed in your question, but it will cut down a lot of boilerplate in a larger code base. I've written [a blog post about using Shapeless](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/solving-problems-in-a-generic-way-using-shapeless), which might be helpful for the scenario you've described. Sorry for the shameless plug.

Comment: @Jaakko Thanks for the ref. to the blog post.

Answer (score 1):

This `afoo` implicit is not only useless in the presence of the other three, but even bad, because it will fail with a `MatchError` on the `new A {}` value.

I don't see why you would need such instance of `Foo[A]` when you have implicits that cover all possible (valid) values of type `A` and `afoo` doesn't add anything.

I can imagine that if you have a function

```
def foo(a: A)(implicit f: Foo[A]): String = f.foo(a)
```

Then, of course, neither of `a1foo`, `a2foo` or `a3foo` will fit. `afoo` will, so `foo(A1())` will compile and work fine, but `foo(new A {})` will also compile, and fail with a `MatchError`. By the way, if the call `foo(new A {})` is present in code, it will compile with a warning about non-exhaustive match, but if it's not, it will compile silently.

So the solution to this is to modify `foo`, to take a more precise type:

```
def foo[X <: A](a: X)(implicit f: Foo[X]): String = f.foo(a)
```

Now `foo(A1())` will compile and pick `a1foo` (same with `A2` and `A3`), while `foo(new A {})` just won't compile (because it shouldn't).

---

#### Update

If you still want to have an instance of `Foo[A]` as a default case, you can change your code like this:

```
object Foo extends Foo_1 {

  implicit val a1foo: Foo[A1] = ...
  implicit val a2foo: Foo[A2] = ...
  implicit val a3foo: Foo[A3] = ...
}

trait Foo_1 {
  // this implicit has a lower priority:
  implicit val afoo: Foo[A] = new Foo[A] { def foo(a: A) = "A" }
}
```

Now `foo(new A {})` or `foo(A2(): A)` will compile and both return `"A"`.

**P.S.** by the way, it's [recommended](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-801) to write explicit type of implicits.